# How to add a mouseover summary in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, winforms, intellisense

I would like to add a summary to my function that when I call the function, I can hover over the name of the function to see what it does. It would be nice if I could do the same thing for each of the parameters.

I want this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

Comment: There is a Third-Party product called [GhostDoc](https://submain.com/ghostdoc/) that can help with this. Probably lots of others as well, but GhostDoc is the one I am familiar with :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your cursor immediately above the function/sub you would like to add the summary to

[image]

Type the comment symbol for the language you are using three times, in vb.net it is this `'` symbol.
You should then see some auto-generated code for the summary.

[image: ![enter image description here]

If there are any parameters in the method you are adding the summary to, there will be a spot to enter descriptions for these as well.

[image]

Enter your summary in the space indicated. You should now be seeing these descriptions when you call the method elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your comment by using a summary tag  and below your comment, coding your method or Function.
for example:

```
    ///<summary>
    ///This is a comment
    ///<para>This is a Paragraph</para>
    ///</summary>
    public void Comment()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
    }
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUfvQ.png)

Comment: This is a vb.net question. You have provided c# answer.

Comment: Oops. sorry I didn't pay attention